# Android move from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity, twitter

I was having some problem for Android activity transition. Basically what I am trying to do is share text to Twitter. However, when I open up the twitter content, it took quite a few seconds to load up the content and resulting in the white blank activity for a few seconds.

And here is my codes, when my button onClick, I am executing the loading dialog:

```
ivTwitterShare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Thread newThread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        super.run();
                        sleep(10000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    } finally {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse(tweetUrl));
                        startActivity(intent);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            };
            newThread.start();
            new LoadTwitterTask().execute();
        }
    });

private class LoadTwitterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading Twitter...",
                "Retrieving Twitter information, please wait...", false,
                false);
        EventDialogueBox.customizeDialogueBox(context, progressDialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter <= 4) {
                    this.wait(50);
                    counter++;
                    publishProgress(counter * 25);
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    }
}
```

However, my problem now is the white blank page before the content is loaded up still there. What I wanted is firstly, the loading dialog will show. Then, at the same time, the twitter intent is loading. Once finish loaded up the content, then dialog will be dismissed.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why sleep for 10sec?

Comment: Because the content only loaded up after some time. So I set it to sleep for 10 sec. Am I doing wrongly?

Comment: @TarunVarshney Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Actually,I am not understanding why you have written AsyncTask. why you are sleeping in between

Comment: Because what I am trying to do is when the button on click, the loading dialog will shows up. At the same time, the twitter intent is loading so that when the loading dialog disappear, the content will be loaded up instead of just showing a blank white activity for a few seconds

Comment: @TarunVarshney I have to sleep it for 10 secs because if I do not do so, it will shows me a white and blank page for a few secs because the page itself is still trying to load up the content